# Rosplay "Bag time" starts 20 sec after rosrecord

Tags: ros

I'm using Rosbag to record a F1 robot simulated in Gazebo.
When i record the F1 everything is OK but qhen i use "Rosbag play" the record is not synchronized with the movement of the F1 that i recorded.
The "Bag time" starts in the second 20 but the duration starts in second 0 so the F1 turns early

I've tried with "rosparam set use_sim_time true" and "rosbag play xxxx.bag --clock" but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your rosbag command to record the topics

Comment: I've tried reccording only one topic: "rosbag record rosout tf /F1ROS/cmd_vel" and i've tried recording all the topics: "rosbag record -a", but any of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the topics you record publish their first message after 20 seconds. Thus, when the first 20 seconds are empty, rosbag play skips this delay.
Just record more topics which also start to publish at your desired time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've tried record all the topics and i find something interesting. The problem is not the reply starts 20 sec after. The problem is that the reply is at real time and the F1 movement depends on gazebo speed so the reply is faster.
How can i  synchronize the time of the reply to gazebo's time?

Comment: I think what you would like to achieve is, that Gazebo is synchronized to your clock which is generated by the `rosbag play` command, right? This is currently not possible as discussed [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16074/using-an-external-simulation-clock/), as Gazebo can only be the one-and-only clock source. Doing it the other way around is not solved either (as far as I know), but you might want to have a look [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/678). If you find a solution, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's all i want to know!